# how to keep selected value on Yii2 html::dropddownlist?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model, yii2-validation

i have the following code in my view:

```html
<?=Html::dropdownList('region',null,
ArrayHelper::map(Ethioregion::find()->all(),'region','region'),[
        'prompt' => 'Select Region..','style'=>'width:200px',]) ?>
```

and submit button

```html
 <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['name' => 'dele','class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

my code working well but I have one big problem.
I select a region and click the search button, the result comes correctly, and 10 result is shown per page when I click the next page, it gives me false data, I notice this is due to the selected value on the dropdownlist is reset. I tried both making " Selected'=> true, and  'Selected'=>'selected', but it does not work. so how can I make the selected value on dropdownlist and checkboxlist will be selected after the page is loading?
thanks

Comment: you can use the `activeDropdownList` or use `ActiveForm` instead

Comment: i want to display dropdown values form a table without using models, so can you show me how can  use using activedropdownlist or activeform? thanks

Comment: do mark the answer as correct if it worked so others having the same issue also benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple, you must pass integer `$region_id` only:

```
<?=Html::dropdownList('region', $region_id,
ArrayHelper::map(Ethioregion::find()->all(),'region','region'),[
        'prompt' => 'Select Region..','style'=>'width:200px',]) ?>
```

Comment: i tried to give the primary key of the ethioregion table that is id, i modified my code like this <?=Html::DropDownList('region','id',
ArrayHelper::map(Ethioregion::find()->all(),'id','region'),['Selected'=>'selected',
        'prompt' => 'Select Region..','style'=>'width:200px',]) ?>      and i tried 'Selected'=>true, but still not working, when the button is clicked  i just want to keep the selected value untill i  select other, how can i show this using activedropdownlist, or using this dropdownlist code? thanks  for ur  help